# jQuery error on loading materialize with webpack Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, webpack, materialize

I would like use http://materializecss.com/ on Laravel 5.4 (compiled with webpack).

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('materialize-css');
// or
// require('materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js');
// but same issue

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

This is my code but the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).materialbox is not a function

It work with this :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
      $('.modal').modal();
      $('.parallax').parallax();
   });
</script>
```

But if I put `jquery document ready` in app.js, it doesn't work :

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/materialize.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

app.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

Comment: why do you use `require()`?

Comment: @Thomas Because that's the modern, recommended way. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this kind of issue with materialize-css  in Laravel 5.4, and my quick fix was to download the materializecss source to /resources/assets/ manually.
This is what my directory looks like now,

```
/resources
----/js
-------app.js
-------bootstrap.js
----/materialize
-------/css
-------/fonts
-------/js
```

Then, on my `bootstrap.js`, I added this code

`require('../materialize/js/materialize.js');`

And this solved my problem.

Comment: When I try this and run npm run dev I get the error This dependency was not found:

* hammerjs in ./resources/assets/js/materialize-js/js/materialize.js